# Where can I find Anri?

Tags: dark-souls-3

***I'm currently looking for Anri.***

She *should* be at Yorshka church (in Irithyll). Here's what I've done so far in this quest :

1. meet her once in Carthus catacombs (at the beginning)
2. beat Wolnir
3. and then, I killed Horace

Now, I just can't find her. There's only a blue light where I met her at the beginning of Carthus catacombs.

Is there a way to find her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably still need to meet her a 2nd time in the Catacombs. She's on a narrow path on a ledge above the long bridge that you can chop down to descend into Smouldering Lake.

Basically, go to where all those skeletons spawn and look for a narrow path that goes to a higher elevation and twists to run parallel to the bridge. She's at the end of that path. If you're standing on the middle of the bridge and heading from Wolnir to where all those skeletons spawn, turn left and look up, and you should see the ledge I'm talking about.

Comment: @PapaStan That's not true, or at least not always. I found Anri there (for the first time) after killing Wolnir but before Pontiff.

Comment: @enguerranws Did you check the second spot ?

Comment: Yes, there's no light there, just on the first spot... Probably because I never met her at the second spot.

Comment: In fact, she was on the second spot, I checked the wrong place. FTR : I killed Horace and spoke to her after beating Wolnir and going to Yorshka Church, so, when I came back to Yorshka, Anri was there, not the Pilgrim (so I couldn't kill him). So I had to follow the lord of hollows questline.

Answer (score 2):

OK I thought it was broken, but here's how I fix Anri not spawning in the church. If you killed the Pontiff Knight before advancing Anri to the church, she doesn't show up if you just warp via bonfires after the catacombs.

I ended up just running through again from Wolner, and i think after the bridge with the doll needed is what might trigger her to spawn at the church. Anyhow after running all the way through to the church again, she was there, then i ran to the Pontiff Knight's room and hit the bonfire again, and she was gone from the church after that. Rest of the quest line is normal after that.